# How to return a string with line breaks as \n characters

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the text from a TextView

```
 String textString = textView.getText().toString();
```

The problem is that if the text in the text view has line breaks like this for example

```
 My 
 Sentence has
 line breaks
```

When I log the text to the console

```
 Log.v("TAG",textString);
```

Or if I set the text to a TextView

```
 textView.setText(textString);
```

The result is always displayed with actual line breaks

```
 My 
 Sentence has
 line breaks
```

And not with the escape characters which is how I want it

```
 My\nSentence has\nline breaks
```

I know this is a really bad explanation, but how to get the text from the text view with the actual characters that represent the line breaks.

Comment: The `String` class has some methods for replacing strings with other strings.  Look up the javadoc.

Comment: You can replace `\n` with `\\n` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 String demo = edit_new.getText().toString().replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"),"\\n" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to format the String that we would represent in Java as

```
String test = "My\nSentence has\nline breaks";
```

as follows:

```
My\nSentence has\nline breaks
```

i.e. replacing each newline character with a backslash followed by a `'n'` character.

One solution is to use `String.replaceAll`.  For example, if you know that the line breaks are strictly newline characters then.

```
String unbroken = broken.replaceAll("\n", "\\\\n");
```

If the line break could be a platform specific line break then:

```
String unbroken = broken.replaceAll("\r\n|\n|\r", "\\\\n");
```

Note that the Java `Pattern` will treat a bare CR or NL in the regex as a literal character.  However in the replacement string, we need a literal backslash character ... hence it needs to be double-escaped.  Another way to write it would be:

```
String unbroken = broken.replaceAll("\n", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\n"));
```

Refer to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) for more details ... and the definitive explanation for the need to handle backslashes as special in the replacement string.